# Unreal Engine 5 Video Streaming

Tags: javascript, api, networking, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I want to show videos in my Unreal Project, I've implemented the basic Stream Media Player of unreal and when I use the [unreal sample video](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/Attachments/working-with-media/integrating-media/MediaFramework/HowTo/StreamMediaSource/SampleVideo.mp4) it works great, but when I try it with a link from my backend I get this error "The byte stream type of the given URL is unsupported".

What type of API should I implement to get this functionality? The backend is in Javascript.

Comment: Check what byte stream type the video player supports?

Comment: I tried MP4 and HLS which are both supported. I've noticed that links that download the video do not work while a link similar to the sample that automatically plays the video in browser works.